# Travel from Lisbon to Tbilisi, through Amsterdam and Kiev

Tags: passports, ukraine

I am going to travel to Tbilisi (Georgia) from Lisbon. Georgia has an agreement with the EU so I don't need a passport (ID card is enough) but I'm travelling through Amsterdam (no passport needed) and Kiev (passport is needed to travel to).

But since I'm transiting, do I need a passport?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.ukrconsul.org/visa/visa_drops.htm), you still need a valid passport in order to transit Ukraine.

Answer (score 2):

You can look more for more specific information then the Visa page from [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=PT&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GE&EM=NL&TR=UA&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) which is in use by the airlines:

> Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> - Transit refused to holders of National ID Cards issued to
>   nationals of Portugal.

So passport is required for transit through Kiev.

**EDIT**

Link above is broken.

Information from [KLM Timatic page](https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm):

> Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> - Transit refused to holders of National ID Cards issued to nationals of Portugal.
> - Except when transiting through Kiev Boryspil (KBP) on Ukraine International Airlines (PS).
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.

Having been to Boryspil last week I haven't seen any other airline flying to Kiev...  Or may be I wasn't there late enough to see any EU based airlines...

Comment: That is either a very poorly worded restriction or a very restrictive one.

Comment: Like I said, the info used to be incomplete. Now it says "Transit refused to holders of National ID Cards issued to nationals of *insert EU Country*, except when transiting through Kiev Boryspil on Ukraine International Airlines". I think UIA notified IATA after I raised the issue with them.

Comment: @Crazydre Even then it would seem to imply that holding an ID card disqualifies you from transiting even if you also had a passport (or visa or anything you might otherwise need...).

Comment: @Relaxed Current Timatic only disqualifies nationals of Portugal

Comment: @Karlson Maybe (did you try to enter another citizenship?) but that's also not the point. Surely nationals for Portugal can transit with a passport like everybody else and not only if they don't hold a national ID card.

Comment: @Karlson The current info does not restrict Portuguese, or any EEA/Swiss nationals

Comment: @Relaxed The latest Timatic states all EEA/Swiss nationals can Transit at Kiev with an ID Card. And this is the case, if the destination country (for example Moldova or Georgia) accepts it for entry and the passenger stays in the Transit zone

Comment: @Relaxed Checked a few others.  You're right.  Only if you transit with UIA it is allowed.  Irrespective of that it seems that the only way "transit" is possible is with UIA since other airlines arrive at night and leave in the morning (at least according to the timetables)

Comment: @Karlson I actually asked a qustion regarding that: why does Timatic restrict it to UIA? I'm considering flying with UIA Tbilisi-Kiev and from there British Airways to London Heathrow (UIA only serves Gatwick, much less convenient given my destination). If I print the British airways Boarding pass in advance in Tbilisi AND travel with only Hand luggage (meaning there's no risk of having to clear Immigration for those purposes), could I take this route? Thing is I won't be able to bring my passport to Tbilisi due to a visa application. The Transit area in Kiev is open 24/7 BTW

Comment: @Crazydre Even in the new Boryspil I wouldn't spend the night at the airport even in International transit area.  As far as international transit I don't know if there is a way to bypass immigration completely unless you get into the airport through a jetway, which you may or may not.  The only positive is that flight from Tbilisi arrives at 7:50 and flight to Heathrow leaves at 2pm, which seems more unusual for European airlines.

Comment: @Karlson Ah, didn't know there were two different areas you could arrive at. I'm familiar with the one where the Transit corridor is right next to immigration

Comment: @Crazydre Didn't notice it when we were passing immigration.  I was flying to Ukraine.

Answer (score 2):

Bumping old post for future reference:

The IATA database used to contain slightly wrong info. You can Transit Kiev at least if you have a through ticket on Ukraine International Airlines, using an EU ID Card.

It's been updated since, however